# R-How do I apply a for loop across multiple data frames?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, statistics-bootstrap

In R, I have 3 dataframes that are similar to the sample versions I have provided below.  The first `Data` is the primary data set, the `TW` and `UW` dataframes have a similar variable as `Data` (`MN-mapping_for_N`), and then 1000 different values for each variable (`N48`) etc. I provided 3 for my purposes here.

```
Data<-matrix(c(4720,44.29,"Work or Private Clinic",N48,2659,55.05,"Hospital",N1,1612,59.99,"No Care",N48),ncol = 4,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(Data)<-c("studyid", "Pred_ex", "wherecare", "MN-mapping_for_N")
Data<-data.frame(Data)


TW<-matrix(c("N48",0.07,0.08,0.09,"N1",0.10,0.11,0.12,"N2",0.02,0.03,0.04,"N3",0.04,0.05,0.06),ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(TW)<-c("MN-mapping_for_N","draw1","draw2","draw3")`
TW<-data.frame(TW)

    UW<-matrix(c("N48",0.71,0.81,0.91,"N1",0.11,0.111,0.131,"N2",0.021,0.031,0.041,"N3",0.041,0.051,0.061),ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(UW)<-c("MN-mapping_for_N","draw1","draw2","draw3")`
UW<-data.frame(UW)
```

My goal is to create a new column with values from a randomly selected column from the `UT` and `TW` data, the correct one to draw from is predicated on the value in `Data$wherecare`

I have been using a mix of dplyr and the match function combined with a couple of functions of my own creation. Currently this looks like

```
drawselect<-function(x) {
samplepick<-sample(2:1001,1)
select(x,1,num_range("draw",samplepick))
 }

DALY_FX_LT_NR<-function(x){
 draw_T_DW<-drawselect(TW)
  draw_UT_DW<-drawselect(UW)
  drawnames.TW<-colnames((draw_T_DW))
  drawnames.UT<-colnames(draw_UT_DW)
  UT.draw<-drawnames.UT[2]
  T.draw<-drawnames.T[2]
  print(UT.draw)       
  print(T.draw)
  newdf<-x %>% mutate(DW=NA)
  for(i in 1:nrow(newdf)){
if(newdf$wherecare[i]!= "No Care"){
  newdf$DW=draw_T_DW[,2][match(newdf$`MN-mapping_for_N`,draw_T_DW$`MN-mapping_for_N`)]
  next
}else if(newdf$wherecare[i]=="No Care"){
  newdf$DW=draw_UT_DW[,2][match(newdf$`MN-mapping_for_N`,draw_UT_DW$`MN-mapping_for_N`[i])]
}
 }
newdf
}
```

The code runs, but I can't seem to get it to actually iterate row by row to make it pull from the correct dataframe for draw values (i.e. `UT` or `TW` after going through the `drawselect` function).

So what I get looks like:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------


studyid   Pred_ex        wherecare         MN-mapping_for_N     DW
--------- --------- ---------------------- ------------------ ------
  4720      44.29   Work or Private Clinic        N48          0.08

  2659      55.05          Hospital                N1          0.11

  1612      59.99          No Care                N48          0.08
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I should be getting:

```
     studyid   Pred_ex        wherecare         MN-mapping_for_N    DW
    --------- --------- ---------------------- ------------------ ------
      4720      44.29   Work or Private Clinic        N48          0.08

      2659      55.05          Hospital                N1          0.11

      1612      59.99          No Care                N48          0.81
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The key difference being the 0.81 in the lower right corner, not a big deal in the sample data, but the actual data is several hundred rows long, so I would like to have the function "decide correctly" which dataset to pull from. This value could be 0.71,0.81 or 0.91, any of the `UT` values for `N48` will work.

The ultimate goal will be to use that value in a calculation by multiplying by the `Pred_ex` column, which I can do, then rerun this function many times to bootstrap the data, but until I can get these `if` statements to work correctly I can't do that.  I have also tried using `dplyr::left_join` to match these and had similar problems with the conditional statements not working.  I think the `match` function as its written will work better, but I'm certainly open to anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, thanks to everyone on stack overflow in general, reading your answers to other questions is the main reason I have gotten this far.

Comment: First of all, the example you gave is not compiling. I would suggest staying clear of the `-` sign when you name your variables, it gets super messy. Second, that's not the way to create a data frame. That being said, the functions you provide don't work either. `samplepick` samples between 2 and 1001, while you only have 4 columns in your dfs. This causes problems for the 2nd function. Also `mutate` changes the names, so the `for loop` doesn't work either. I'm editing your data frame creating and `samplepick`.

Answer (score 1):

So you don't need a new function (I kept `drawselect`, you can just do the following:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Data)){
    if (Data$wherecare[i] != "No Care"){
        Data$DW[i]<- drawselect(TW)[which(drawselect(TW)$MN.mapping_for_N == as.character(Data$MN.mapping_for_N[i])), 2]
    } else {
        Data$DW[i]<- drawselect(UW)[which(drawselect(UW)$MN.mapping_for_N == as.character(Data$MN.mapping_for_N[i])), 2]
    }
}

> Data
  studyid Pred_ex              wherecare MN.mapping_for_N   DW
1    4720   44.29 Work or Private Clinic              N48 0.08
2    2659   55.05               Hospital               N1 0.11
3    1612   59.99                No Care              N48 0.81
```

If you want to wrap everything in a function (including `drawselect`), try something along the lines of the following:

```
    DALY_FX_LT_NR<-function(x, y, z){ #x would be Data, y would be TW, z would be UW
 samplepick<-sample(2:(ncol(y)-1),1) 
 for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
    if (x$wherecare[i] != "No Care"){
        x$DW[i]<- y[which(y$MN.mapping_for_N==as.character(x$MN.mapping_for_N[i])), paste0("draw", samplepick)]
    } else {
        x$DW[i]<- z[which(z$MN.mapping_for_N==as.character(x$MN.mapping_for_N[i])), paste0("draw", samplepick)]
    }
  }
  return(x)
}

> DALY_FX_LT_NR(x = Data, y = TW, z = UW)
  studyid Pred_ex              wherecare MN.mapping_for_N   DW
1    4720   44.29 Work or Private Clinic              N48 0.09
2    2659   55.05               Hospital               N1 0.12
3    1612   59.99                No Care              N48 0.91
```

Comment: Hey @YannisVassiliadis, thank you helping with this.  In the MN.mapping_for_N column in the results above, all of the results are N48, but in the data I provided (apologies for not making the DF correctly) one of them differs (N1).  This might be due to when you created the data and not anything with the function.

Comment: @user8005527 you're right, I did put N48 for all, instead of N1 for the middle one. In any case, I'm editing the code chunks above, but it still works.

Comment: Regardless, when I try to run the function I get the error "Error in y$MN.mapping_for_N: $ is an invalid operator for atomic vectors" .  If I try to run the loop I just get back the original Data, the DW column doesn't show up.  Do you have a sense of where I might have gone wrong? Thanks for following up

Comment: OK there was one more mistake in the function, but I fixed it now. Just to be clear, all inputs of the function `x=Data, y=TW, z=UW` should be data.frames. From the error you're reporting in your comment, that doesn't seem to be the case (maybe they're matrices?)

Comment: your last fix definitely makes the function work well, however when I try and apply it to my larger dataset the DW column doesn't get created. My only thought is that the `wherecare` variable is a factor in the original data, could this be causing this?

Comment: Honestly I don't know about that. I'd try one of 2 things though. First, try to create DW before calling the function, and then populate it with NAs ( `Data$DW<- NA`). If that doesn't work, try changing the class of `wherecare` to character.

Comment: Hi @user8005527. I think your new trouble might have to do with the use of a "-" in the name of your MN-mapping_for_N variable. I would check whether all data frames have the same resulting columns names and if they match the one used in the code. If they are different, check if you are building your data frames with exactly the same funtion. For example, `TW<-data.frame(TW)` will replace the dash with a point, 
while `TW<-as.data.frame(TW)` will mantain the dash. As @YannisVassiliadis said, I would avoid using the dash in the variable names.

Comment: Thanks, @stormsurge, that did mess me up at first, however I fixed it and got the functions to work well.  I've been trying to apply it to my real data without success.  I keep getting many repeats of the error message "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length, number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length".  I suspect this is my fault due to supplying example data that had the same length in all cases.  Can the solution be adjusted to deal with different lengths of data frames?

Comment: Hi @user8005527, I haven't be able to reproduce your error message. 
However, if TW and UW have different number of columns you'd like to use a specific samplepick value for each one.
`samplepick_y<-sample(2:(ncol(y)-1),1)` and `samplepick_z<-sample(2:(ncol(z)-1),1)`. Also, make sure that TW and UW 
take into account all the cases that appear in your primary data set, otherwise you'll get an error because
 `which` won't find any value and will return a vector of length 0. 
Maybe with additional information about how different your 3 dataframes are we could find out how to solve it.